# Error in adding properties my object Server OPC-UA

Tags: opc-ua, open62541

I am using the open62541 library [1.1.2-216-g50933d8].
Tell me how to add engineering units to my node?
Му Node create:

```
bool isOk = true;

 UA_VariableAttributes valueAttr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
 UA_Variant_init(&valueAttr.value);

 UA_Float valueVal = 0;
 UA_Variant_setScalar(&valueAttr.value, &valueVal, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_FLOAT]);

 std::string description = "Value Params";
 valueAttr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT(const_cast<char*>(lt), const_cast<char*>(description.c_str()));
 valueAttr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT(const_cast<char*>(lt), const_cast<char*>("Value"));

 if(UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, UA_NODEID_NULL,
                              getNodeId(),
                              UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASCOMPONENT),
                              UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(nsIndexBrowser, const_cast<char*>("Value")),
                              UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEDATAVARIABLETYPE),
                              valueAttr, nullptr, &value_) != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
 {
     return isOk;
 }
```

I tried to do this:

```
    UA_EUInformation eu;
    eu.namespaceUri = UA_STRING("somecompany.com");
    eu.unitId = -1;
    eu.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT(const_cast<char*>(lt), const_cast<char*>(typeSigne_->getEUid().c_str()));
    eu.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT(const_cast<char*>(lt), const_cast<char*>(typeSigne_->getEUid().c_str()));

    UA_StatusCode status = UA_Server_writeObjectProperty_scalar(server,
                                                                value_,
                                                                UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(nsIndexBrowser, "EngineeringUnits"),
                                                                &eu,
                                                                &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_EUINFORMATION]);

    if(status != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
    {
        return isOk;
    }
```

But I got the error code UA_STATUSCODE_BADNOMATCH

I tried to do this:

```
 UA_EUInformation eu;
    eu.namespaceUri = UA_STRING("somecompany.com");
    eu.unitId = -1;
    eu.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT(const_cast<char*>(lt), const_cast<char*>(typeSigne_->getEUid().c_str()));
    eu.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT(const_cast<char*>(lt), const_cast<char*>(typeSigne_->getEUid().c_str()));
    UA_VariableAttributes enAttr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    UA_VariableAttributes_init(&enAttr);
    enAttr.dataType = UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_EUINFORMATION].typeId;
    enAttr.userWriteMask = UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_READ;
    UA_Variant_setScalarCopy(&enAttr.value, &eu, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_EUINFORMATION]);

    UA_StatusCode status = UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, UA_NODEID_NULL,
                                                     value_,
                                                     UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASPROPERTY),
                                                     UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(nsIndexBrowser, "EngineeringUnits"),
                                                     UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_PROPERTYTYPE),
                                                     enAttr,
                                                     nullptr, &enUnitNodeUnits_);
    if(status != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
    {
        return isOk;
    }
```

But I got the error code UA_STATUSCODE_BADTYPEMISMATCH

I also tried these examples https://groups.google.com/g/open62541/c/90dpSO2Wu7E/m/mNUknnRSCAAJ . They don't work.

And in general, I tried to add any properties to my object, but it didn't work out either (UA_STATUSCODE_BADTYPEMISMATCH).

I don't understand why I can't do it?